# Not Able to Generate Thumbnail Image from the Recorded Video

Tags: iphone, uiimage, video-thumbnails

I am Generating the thumbnail from the recorded video which is stored in the documents directory that video can't not be more than to the 1 minute. till the recording time everything works properly.as i try to generate the thumbnail from that recorded video got nothing.i have used the two way for the same

- **By using the MPMoviePlayerController**

  ```
  -(void)generateThumbnail:(NSURL*)assetURL{

   if(assetURL){

     MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:assetURL];
    UIImage  *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

    //AT THIS POINT AS I CHECK IT THIS thumbnail contains 0X000000
     player = nil;
     if (thumbnail) {
         //will use that image to further
     }
    else {
       //here wil doing some intimation
   }
   }
  }
  ```

  As Above method finish with the execution got these logs

  Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
  Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
  [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
  [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
  [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
  [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
  [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player:1)
- **By using AVAssetImageGenerator**

  ```
    -(void)genrateThumbnailImageFromAsset:(AVAsset*)_assetObject size:(CGSize)size forTime:(CMTime)thumbTime
    {
   __weak typeof(self) wself = self;
   __block UIImage * thumbNailImage = nil;
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:_assetObject];
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;

   AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error)
   {
     switch (result) {

      case AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded:{
          /*get the generated image*/
          thumbNailImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:im];
         // We finished updating the image. Set the visual UI button to the uploaded image
          if (thumbNailImage) {
              //using accordingly
          }
          else
          {
               //using accordingly
          }
      }
       break;

      case AVAssetImageGeneratorFailed:{
           //using  accordingly
          NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
      }
          break;

      case AVAssetImageGeneratorCancelled:{
         //using  accordingly
          NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
      }
          break;

      default:
          break;
     }
   };

   generator.maximumSize = size;
   [generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];    
  }
  ```

By Above got nothing .... still looking for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the way, actually i have mistakenly placed the wrong method for creating the URL of that recorded video

I was using `urlWithString` instead of `fileURLWithPath` as i used `fileURLWithPath` everything working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1,1));
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:assetURL];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();         
UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

[player stop];
```

Comment: you just pasted similar code m using,tried to add `stop` methods still not succeeded ...!!!!!

Comment: are you getting proper URL? Please NSLog your URL.

Comment: i ma getting URL properly and  have checked each thing carefully, have you read log comes as `execution of first way`finishes.

Comment: Try with this:  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1,1));
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:assetURL];

                    UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

                    //Player autoplays audio on init
                    [player stop];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

Comment: dude i mistakenly used `urlWithString` instead of `fileURLWithPath`, as i changed that method, everything works properly, well thanks for replying me...... +1 for the same